# how to maintain different session in different tabs in spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, session

I want to manage 2 different session in 2 different tabs of same browser. so I stored data based on logged user id in session storage. i.e like this

```
  <% int logedId=(int) session.getAttribute("loggedUserId");%>  



 loggeduserID=<%=logedId %> console.log("logged id:",loggeduserID)


console.log("logged id:",loggeduserID)
function poplateOrganizations(callback){
    var selectedOrgId = 0;
    if(sessionStorage.getItem(loggeduserID)!==undefined && sessionStorage.getItem(loggeduserID)!==null){
        organizationPopulation(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(loggeduse
    }
    else{
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"../getOrg,
        contentType:"application/json",
        success:function(response){

           sessionStorage.setItem(loggeduserID,JSON.stringify(response));

           selectedOrgId=$('#organizationName option:selected').val();
            callback(selectedOrgId.toString());

        }

    });
```

but now the problem is while logging it is working correct way but if any of the page refreshed it's data is being modified by first cache, I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413892/is-it-possible-to-maintain-different-sessions-users-in-different-window-tabs-u) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479995/managing-webapp-session-data-controller-flow-for-multiple-tabs/4480310#4480310)  in last it says spring will support this functionality. does it support now? if yes please can anyone explain me how? or URL rewriting is my only option?